# I'm doing an apprenticeship but I feel as if I'm being used as cheap labour

Tags: communication, united-kingdom

I'm working as an apprentice programmer for a very small company, as I am under 18 and in the UK, I am getting the minimum wage for an apprentice. The apprenticeship is full-time for 15 months.

My problem is I am not being taught by the other guys there, they only give me jobs, and I have to learn myself to get it done. Both my brothers are in engineering apprenticeships where they are directly tutored the whole time, and they are receiving the correct rate of pay, whereas I feel as if I'm being used as cheap labour, because it's nothing like an apprenticeship at all.

My question to you is this:

Should I be complaining to my manager about the lack of tutoring, or should I be challenging him as to why I'm being used as cheap labour?

Comment: To clarify for the non-UK people: is this a summer internship or a full-time position?

Comment: @Lilienthal Full time position, 15 months

Comment: @Aleksandr are you doing any formal training at all ? and 15 months is not  a normal apprenticeship.

Comment: Id also suggest joining a trade union Prospect would be the appropriate one here

Comment: Apart from other ideas put in the answer, mention your boss that you feel that, as you lack both experience and guidance, maybe your code is of low quality, and that you desire to improve both for yourself and for improving the delivered work. Try to avoid mentioning salary, learn what you can and leave them (or make them pay you more) when you are formed.

Comment: Is the issue the lack of training or the lack of pay? For example, if they increased the training for you would you feel the pay is fair

Comment: This same thing happened to me in America only I didn't even get paid, it was a mandatory (for my education) unpaid internship.  They stuck me in the basement with work to do, NO ONE to go to with questions or concerns.  Suffice to say I did poor work, got my hours finished and got out of there fast.

Comment: Take a trip to the job centre. They should be able to give you advice

Comment: @Pepone - There are trade unions for computer programmers?

Comment: Sounds like you're being paid to learn on your own. Since you know other people with higher paying internships, why did you accept this one? If they promised to teach/mentor you and they are not, you should complain about that.

Comment: @JeffO yes Prospect represents a lot of technical staff in the UK  and there is a sector specifically for telecoms and IT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Complaining might not go over well, but mention to him that your expectations for mentorship are not being met, and ask for more pair programming opportunities. You don't have to get hours worth of help at a time, but if you can ask them to come over and help you with something that you're struggling with, that would seem to be an improvement over your current situation.

Programming is different work from a lot of other fields. Even very good and experienced programmers spend a lot of time searching for the right way to do things. It's also hard for some people to teach others that sort of skill, even if they appear to be very good at it. You may be unfortunately working with such programmers.

As for being cheap labour, you're not even 18 yet, that's what you're paying to get entry into the field and to get real-world experience. Good programmers are hard to come by, so just keep on trying to become as "good" as you can, and you'll eventually be able to command even better salaries than your brothers.

Answer (score 6):

You are studying towards some form of qualification at the same time aren't you?

> study towards a related qualification (usually one day a week)

[uk gov apprentice guidelines](https://www.gov.uk/apprenticeships-guide/overview)

If you are just working a 40 hour week at apprentice rates with no study then that is (probably) illegal since you should be paid a regular minimum wage for someone under 18 who isn't studying.

> 2014 (current rate)   £6.50   £5.13   £3.79   **£2.73**

[National minimum wage](https://www.gov.uk/national-minimum-wage-rates)

I don't have a complete understanding of the rules but a 'proper' apprenticeship is normally in combination with a college and your employer and should be certified in some way. The education element lets them pay you less while they teach you. I have worked in companies that take on apprentices and they have generally worked out well. At my last small company the two guys had gone from your situation to be qualified engineering technicians (one with a degree).

If you're getting experience and qualifications you might be earning less at the minute than someone stacking shelves in ASDA but you're gaining something that will be worth far more a few years down the line so don't give up.

Answer (score 1):

> I feel as if I'm being used as cheap labour, because it's nothing like an apprenticeship at all

Unfortunately, that is precisely what's happening. Once upon a time, apprenticeships were a scheme by which young people could receive a decent education in a particular trade whilst on the job. Indeed, the ones your brothers are undertaking sound legitimate. However, since their revival in the last decade (and particularly since the financial crisis in 2008), apprenticeships have increasingly become a loophole by which employers have been able to exploit people like yourself by paying below the minimum wage and providing minimal/no education.

You may be able to argue to your manager that, because what you're doing cannot justifiably be described as an apprenticeship, you should at least be paid the normal minimum wage - which for you would be £3.79 an hour. That said, the minimum wage for apprentices is due to jump from £2.73 to £3.30 in October anyway, so you may be in a better position to negotiate a higher wage after that.

In the meantime, I'd recommend joining a trade union - most offer reasonable rates for those at your level of pay. If you're aware of one in your workplace then join that one, otherwise [Unite](http://www.unitetheunion.org/) or [Prospect](https://www.prospect.org.uk/) are pretty good.

Answer (score -3):

You should do neither.

Complaining and challenging are negative behaviors, that might result in negative actions.

You applied to an internship knowing that it has a low pay. They arent paying you to learn, they are paying you to work.  Educating you is a benefit of an internship, but not their purpose.

However, you feel you arent getting enough education out of your internship.  Go to your supervisor and politely explain that you are interested in learning more than you are.  Ask about the possibility of having a mentor/mentee relationship and explain how it would be a benefit to you and the company.

Comment: An apprenticeship is not an unpaid internship! and the whole point of an internship is they train you - there are strict laws about it in the USA

Comment: @Pepone While still correct, I feel the need to point out that Asker is from the UK - but there *are* still laws about apprenticeships in the UK, and how much you are supposed to get paid for it.